# How can I split `div` contents into an array, display 1st index of array and then allow user to click arrow to display next index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Lets say I have `<div class="list">Cheese/Beans/Chili Powder</div>`.

I want to display this to the user: `<div class="list">Cheese</div>` and then allow the user to click an arrow to change it to `<div class="list">Beans</div>` and a different arrow to change it back.

Could some please help me do that?

Comment: Why not use an actual list? `ul`/`li`

Comment: Currently my data is already delimited with "/".

Comment: So split it on `"/"` and build a list...

Comment: it would help if the parent div had an id attribute or another class you could use as a selector so if that div gets updated dynamically it doesn't update the inner divs to split and rearrange the content, or use `ul/li` as @Shmiddty suggested

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought would work, but I don't know how to do that. I am learning Ruby, but I need some help with making this adjustment to the rails output.

Comment: In the use-case you provided, is the "Chili Power" text ever displayed to the user via these "arrow clicks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

Assuming your list is `.list`:

```
var l = $('.list')
l.data('items', l.text().split('/'));
l.data('current', 0);

function display() {
    l.text(l.data('items')[l.data('current')]);
}

function cycle() {
    l.data('current', l.data('current')+1);
    if(l.data('current') >= l.data('items').length) {
        l.data('current', 0);
    }
    display();
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rAYxb/ - Click on the element to cycle through the items

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it properly (with a list): http://jsfiddle.net/TjFLY/1/

```
var data = "Cheese/Beans/Chili Power".split("/"),
    list = $("<ul>").addClass("list");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    list.append($("<li>").text(data[i]))
}
list.children().eq(0).addClass("active");
$("<a>").attr("href", "#").addClass("prev").text("<").appendTo("body").click(function() {
    var prev = $(".list .active").prev();
    if (prev.length)
        $(".list .active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
});
$("body").append(list);
$("<a>").attr("href", "#").addClass("next").text(">").appendTo("body").click(function() {
    var next = $(".list .active").next();
    if (next.length)
        $(".list .active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
});​
```

With this CSS to show/hide the list items:

```
.list li{
    display:none;
}
.list li.active{
    display:block;
}
```